# Combining two lists and removing duplicates, without removing duplicates in original list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that i need to combine where the second list has any duplicates of the first list ignored. .. A bit hard to explain, so let me show an example of what the code looks like, and what i want as a result.

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]

second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

# The result of combining the two lists should result in this list:
resulting_list = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9]
```

You'll notice that the result has the first list, *including* its two "2" values, but the fact that second_list also has an additional 2 and 5 value is not added to the first list.

Normally for something like this i would use sets, but a set on first_list would purge the duplicate values it already has. So i'm simply wondering what the best/fastest way to achieve this desired combination.

Thanks.

Comment: What if there are three 2s in `second_list`?

Comment: @balpha: Yea, i haven't fully decided how i want to handle that yet. It is something i had thought about, but left out given my indecision on the matter :)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You need to append to the first list those elements of the second list that aren't in the first - sets are the easiest way of determining which elements they are, like this:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

in_first = set(first_list)
in_second = set(second_list)

in_second_but_not_in_first = in_second - in_first

result = first_list + list(in_second_but_not_in_first)
print(result)  # Prints [1, 2, 2, 5, 9, 7]
```

Or if you prefer one-liners 8-)

```
print(first_list + list(set(second_list) - set(first_list)))
```

Comment: Or this if you need it sorted: print first_list + sorted(set(second_list) - set(first_list))

Comment: List(set(first_list)|set(second_list))        #| is set intersection see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674013/how-to-take-two-lists-and-combine-them-excluding-any-duplicates

Comment: @staticd: Yes, but that gives the wrong answer.  There's only one `2` in your result, when there should be two of them.

Comment: oops. You're right. Totally missed that the first list *was* allowed duplicates. :P

Comment: Note: this solution doesn't preserve the sequence. For that feature, go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319355/2470337 .

Answer (score 131):

```
resulting_list = list(first_list)
resulting_list.extend(x for x in second_list if x not in resulting_list)
```

Comment: Finally an answer that doesn't involve casting into sets! Kudos.

Comment: this is in fact O(n*m) but may be handy when you have list of non-hashable things and performance is not a concern

Comment: What I don't want any duplicated neither from first nor from second?

Comment: This technique preserves the order of attributes in the list, which is not the case with `set`. 

Answer (score 78):

You can use sets:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

resultList= list(set(first_list) | set(second_list))

print(resultList)
# Results in : resultList = [1,2,5,7,9]
```

Comment: Yes Thanks I got it.  This will work fine. resultList= first_list + list(set(second_list) -set(first_list))

Answer (score 30):

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

print( set( first_list + second_list ) )
```

Answer (score 16):

You can bring this down to one single line of code if you use numpy:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [2,4,7,8,9,10,11,12]

sorted(np.unique(a+b))

>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Answer (score 12):

Simplest to me is:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

merged_list = list(set(first_list+second_list))
print(merged_list)

#prints [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: That's a great solution, but keep in mind that it won't work if we try to make array of dictionaries a set e.g. (will raise `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`)

Answer (score 8):

```
resulting_list = first_list + [i for i in second_list if i not in first_list]
```

Comment: setify first_list and you're "set"

Comment: The resulting list won't be sorted.

Comment: What if I also don't want any list to have duplicates at all? this way if one list has duplicates they will return

Answer (score 4):

You can also combine RichieHindle's and Ned Batchelder's responses for an *[average-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906036/320036) O(m+n)* algorithm that preserves order:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

fs = set(first_list)
resulting_list = first_list + [x for x in second_list if x not in fs]

assert(resulting_list == [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9])
```

Note that [`x in s` has a worst-case complexity of *O(m)*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set), so the *worst-case* complexity of this code is still *O(m*n)*.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dict.fromkeys` to return a list with no duplicates:

```py
def mergeTwoListNoDuplicates(list1, list2):
    """
    Merges two lists together without duplicates
    :param list1:
    :param list2:
    :return:
    """
    merged_list = list1 + list2
    merged_list = list(dict.fromkeys(merged_list))
    return merged_list
```

Comment: I love this `[*dict.fromkeys(list1+list2)]` formula and use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580634-merge-unique-items-from-multiple-lists-into-a-new-/) :

> resulting_list = list(set().union(first_list, second_list))

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
def union(a,b):
    for e in b:
        if e not in a:
            a.append(e)
```

The union function merges the second list into first, with out duplicating an element of a, if it's already in a. Similar to set union operator. This function does not change b. If a=[1,2,3] b=[2,3,4]. After union(a,b) makes a=[1,2,3,4] and b=[2,3,4]

Answer (score -1):

```
    first_list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
    second_list = [2, 5, 7, 9]

    newList=[]
    for i in first_list:
        newList.append(i)
    for z in second_list:
        if z not in newList:
            newList.append(z)
    newList.sort()
    print newList
```

[1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 9]