# How to take two lists and combine them excluding any duplicates?

Tags: python

I'd like to make one list from two separate lists of unique items.

There are other similar questions but there didn't seem to be any that concerned doing this problem effectively since the lists are a few million items long.

Totally unrelated: am I the only one who hates how the tags suggestion box covers up the "post your question" button?

Comment: Does the order of items in the lists matter?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a `set`.

```
>>> first = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> second = [3, 2, 5, 6, 7]
>>> third = list(set(first) | set(second))      # '|' is union
>>> third
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: How can I do it without using set?

Comment: Hey user225312, do you gain anything by calling set() twice and using union? Instinctively I would just write list(set(first + second)).

Comment: please do note that this approach cannot be used if the lists contain unhashable types (eg. lists of dictionaries)

Comment: Please also note that the resulting list in `third` will not *necessarily* be ordered/sorted, due to the way that sets hash their components. If you need to sort the results, use `sorted()`.

Answer (score 14):

A slightly more efficient way to do it:

```
>>> first = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> second = [3, 2, 5, 6, 7]

# New way
>>> list(set(first + second))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 µs per loop

# Old way
>>> list(set(first) | set(second))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 µs per loop
```

*The new way is more efficient because it has only one set() instead of 2.*

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> l1 = range(10)
>>> l2 = range(5, 15)
>>> set(l1) | set(l2)
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone want to do it without `set()`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
newlist=[]
for i in a:
    newlist.append(i)
for z in b:
    if z not in newlist:
        newlist.append(z)
newlist.sort()
print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean and professional solution:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list1 = [3, 4, 5]
result = list(set().union(list, list1)) # result [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```