# Python: Append a list to an existing list assigned to a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Lets say I have a dict with key= 'keys'

```
>>> keys
'taste'
```

After a few lines..output

```
>>> {'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like')}
```

This code snippet

```
from collections import defaultdict
agent=defaultdict(str)
key_list=[]

key_list=[(keys,tuple(key_list))]
agent=dict(key_list)
#agent[keys]+=key_list
```

What I want to know is, is there a way to lets say I have `agent= {'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like')}`

I want to add to a list

```
key_list=['yuck!','tasty','smoothie']
```

and `agent.setdefault('taste',[]).append(key_list)`

and have output like:

```
 {'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like','yuck!','tasty','smoothie')}
```

instead of

```
{'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like',['yuck!','tasty','smoothie'])}
```

Is there a way to that?

Inshort:

1. I want to add a list to an existing list,which is a value to a key in a dictionary (w/o iterations to find that particular key)
2. Check if the element being fed in as a list already contains that element in that list which is a value to a particular key, say 'taste' here (could be string, as here)

Comment: What you have there is a dict of tuples, which are less convenient to append to than lists. Lists have a method `extend` which adds the individual elements of an additional list instead of adding the list itself.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Can you give an example in the answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

```
>>> tst =  {'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like')}
>>> tst.get('taste', ()) #default to () if does not exist.  
('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like')
>>> key_list=['yuck!','tasty','smoothie']
>>> tst['taste'] = tst.get('taste') + tuple(key_list)
>>> tst
{'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like', 'yuck!', 'tasty', 'smoothie')}
```

To retrieve,

```
>>> tst = {'taste': ('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like', 'yuck!', 'tasty', 'smoothie')}
>>> taste = tst.get('taste')
>>> taste
('sweet', 'sour', 'juicy', 'melon-like', 'yuck!', 'tasty', 'smoothie')
>>> 'sour' in taste
True
>>> 'sour1' in taste
False
```

Comment: you mean instead of get(), tst.setdefault(key,[]).extend(key_list) would that work?

Comment: why do you want to extend? can you not just replace ? that is what `tst.get('taste') + tuple(key_list)` is doing for you .

Comment: in my code agent.setdefault(keys,[]).extend(key_list) worked
Didnt use defaultdict as I didnt know what is agent-defaultdict(type???) I am extend to same list if list in same key.

Comment: Sure, In the question you showed a tuple, so i used that to illustrate. As long as it works, its all cool :)

Comment: Either way setdefault/defaultdict, using lists, it generates duplicates. I would also like to know how can we search for an element in a list as value of a key? you can provide a code eg  in the answer box

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you have three questions here, let's go over them:

1. You can `extend` a list to append elements from another list:
   `[1,2,3].extend([4,5]) # [1,2,3,4,5]`
2. Since you have tuples, which are immutable, you can simply add a tuple to existing one:
   `(1,2,3) + (4,5) # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`
3. If you do not want *duplicates*, you want to use `set`, and you can union them:
   `{1,2}.union({2,3}) # set([1,2,3])`
   see how 2 is not duplicated here. 
   But beware, sets do not keep their order.

In the end, if you want to remove duplicates and don't care about order, you can combine 2 and 3:
`set(old_value).union(set(new_value))`

Otherwise, if you need to preserve order, see this question:
[Combining two lists and removing duplicates, without removing duplicates in original list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319338/combining-two-lists-and-removing-duplicates-without-removing-duplicates-in-orig)

Comment: +1 for multiple solutions and only showing how they work, not coding it for him. Clearly the best answer here, imo.

Comment: @Dmitry Does that work for strings as well, instead of integers?

Answer (score 0):

you want the `extend` function:

```
In [6]: l = [1,2,3]

In [7]: l2 = [4,5]

In [9]: l.extend(l2)

In [10]: l
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but you will need the value of your key to be a list rather than a tuple

Comment: OP shows a dict of tuples instead of lists, so that won't work out of the box. `tuple( list( key_list ).extend( additionalItems ) )` gets closer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove commented an example above in karthikr 's comment. Is that what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `agent`, so the first `defaultdict` is never used. Also, if you change the values, tuples are not the way to go, as they are immutable.

Start out with

```
from collections import defaultdict
agent = defaultdict(list)
```

and then

```
agent[key] += 'item'
```

or

```
agent[key].extend(list_of_items)
```