# Python: Merge words from files to one line

Tags: python, merge, duplicates

I have a list with words out of different textfiles. When I sort this list out and clean them of duplicates I still see multiple words which are the soms but out of different text files, e.g. ['you', 'chainletter.txt'] and ['you', 'grail.txt'] My question is , how could I combine these to give the output ['you', 'chainletter.txt', 'grail.txt']

I'm currently using the following code:
'pearl' module:

```
def make_table(pairs):
    import sort
    import dup
    sort = sort.merge_pairs(pairs)
    nodup = dup.remove_dups(sort)
    print(nodup)
    return nodup
```

And i want my 'search engine' to display words like described above

Comment: Note that when you do 'sort =', you're overwriting the imported module, sort. It might work, but calling your variables something that's already used will cause weird problems at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve overall, but the two problems you mention can be solved as follows:

1. You can use [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to remove duplicates from a list (and list() to turn it back into a list if you like).
2. To add the elements of a list into another list, use [.extend()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.extend)

[This question about merging lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319338/combining-two-lists-and-removing-duplicates-without-removing-duplicates-in-orig) may also be of interest.