# Extracting data from csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with each row containing lists of adjectives.

For example, the first 2 rows are as follows:

```
["happy","sad","colorful"]
["horrible","sad","cheerful","happy"]
```

I want to extract all the data from this file to get a list containing each adjective only one.
(Here, it would be a list as follows :

```
["happy","sad","colorful","horrible","cheerful"]
```

I am doing this using Python.

```
import csv
with open('adj.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    adj_list = list(reader) 
    filtered_list = [] 
    for l in adj_list: 
        if l not in new_list: 
            filtered_list.append(l)
```

Comment: Does this csv literally have brackets in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two lists and removing duplicates, without removing duplicates in original list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319338/combining-two-lists-and-removing-duplicates-without-removing-duplicates-in-orig)

Comment: Should i use pandas or csv module?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: import csv
with open('adj.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    adj_list = list(reader)
    
filtered_list = []
for l in adj_list:
    if l not in new_list:
        filtered_list.append(l)

Comment: You can't just `list(reader)`. That gives you a list of lists. Youll need to extract out each row in a loop, then put all columns in one list

Comment: Every row has different number of elements. How would you suggest i go about it?

Comment: A row of `reader` is iterable. How about a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that "memory is not important" and that one liner is what you are looking for:

```
from itertools import chain
from csv import reader

print(list(set(chain(*reader(open('file.csv'))))))
```

having 'file.csv' content like this:

```
happy, sad, colorful
horrible, sad, cheerful, happy
```

**OUTPUT:**

['horrible', ' colorful', ' sad', ' cheerful', ' happy', 'happy']

You can remove the `list()` part if you don't mind receive a *Python set* instead of a list.

Comment: This too gives a set of lists. I want just a single list with no word repetition.

Comment: @Newbie No set of list, just a set without any string repeat. If want a list and not a set, just add list(). I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only interested in a list of unique words where *order does not matter*:

```
# Option A1
import csv


with open("adj.csv", "r") as f:
    seen = set()
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        for word in line:
            seen.add(word)
list(seen)
# ['cheerful', 'colorful', 'horrible', 'happy', 'sad']
```

More concisely:

```
# Option A2
with open("adj.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    unique_words = {word for line in reader for word in line}

list(unique_words)
```

The `with` statement safely opens and closes the file.  We are simply adding every word to a set.  We cast the filtered result to `list()` and get a list of unique (unordered) words.

---

**Alternatives**

If *ordered does matter*, implement the `unique_everseen` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

From itertools recipes:

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in it.filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

You can manually implement this or install a third-library that implements it for you, such as [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen), e.g. `pip install more_itertools`

```
# Option B
import csv

import more_itertools as mit


with open("adj.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    words = (word for line in reader for word in line)
    unique_words = list(mit.unique_everseen(words))

unique_words
# ['happy', 'sad', 'colorful', 'horrible', 'cheerful']
```