# How to do union of several lists?

Tags: python, list

I was reading this: [Combining two lists and removing duplicates, without removing duplicates in original list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319338/combining-two-lists-and-removing-duplicates-without-removing-duplicates-in-orig) but my need goes beyond. I have at least 30 lists and I need the union without duplicates of all the lists. Right now my first try was just to use + to just append all the member in one great list and then use set to remove duplicates, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution:

**Edit - Adding samples:**

```
list_a = ['abc','bcd','dcb']
list_b = ['abc','xyz','ASD']
list_c = ['AZD','bxd','qwe']
big_list = list_a + list_b + list_c
print list(set(big_list)) # Prints ['abc', 'qwe', 'bcd', 'xyz', 'dcb', 'ASD', 'bxd']
```

My real question is if this the best way to go with this combination?

Comment: Please add an example to your question. Preferably with three lists, not thirty.

Comment: Just perform the "union two lists" operation 29 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can use the `set.update` method with an arbitrary number of iterable arguments.

```
>>> lists = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7]]
>>> result = set()
>>> result.update(*lists)
>>> 
>>> result
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

edit: with your sample data:

```
>>> list_a = ['abc','bcd','dcb']
>>> list_b = ['abc','xyz','ASD']
>>> list_c = ['AZD','bxd','qwe']
>>> 
>>> result = set()
>>> result.update(list_a, list_b, list_c)
>>> result
{'ASD', 'xyz', 'qwe', 'bxd', 'AZD', 'bcd', 'dcb', 'abc'}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, the only thing I add to this was to use
`print(list(result))` because only having `print(result)` give me `set(['abc', 'qwe', 'bcd', 'xyz', 'dcb', 'ASD', 'bxd'])` on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Use `set.union(set1, set2, set3, ..)`.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [2,3,4]
>>> l3 = [3,4,5]
>>> set.union(*[set(x) for x in (l1, l2, l3)])
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

More compact (works for both Py2 and Py3, Thanks @Lynn!):

```
>>> set.union(*map(set, (l1, l2, l3)))
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Both of your snippets actually work for both Python 2 and 3. Your second snippet is missing a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `set.union` has [already been mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063424/4573247), although applied onto each list after first mapping the lists to `set` instances.

As an alternative, the explicit `set` mapping can be omitted, as `set.union`, much like `set.update` (the latter approach covered in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063418/4573247)) also takes arbitrary number of iterable arguments, allowing directly invoking `set.union` over an empty set and the provided lists.

```
>>> list_a = ['abc','bcd','dcb']
>>> list_b = ['abc','xyz','ASD']
>>> list_c = ['AZD','bxd','qwe']

>>> result = set().union(list_a, list_b, list_c)
>>> result
{'ASD', 'xyz', 'qwe', 'bxd', 'AZD', 'bcd', 'dcb', 'abc'}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a function that accepts any number of lists, flattens them and returns the union:

```
from itertools import chain

def union_lists(*iterables):
    union = []
    lookup = set()

    flattened = chain.from_iterable(iterables)

    for item in flattened:
        if item not in lookup:
            lookup.add(item)
            union.append(item)

    return union
```

The benefit of the above function is that it preserves the order of the list items as they are inserted, unlike a `set()`, which is unordered. It however uses a `set()` for checking if items have been added, which is `O(1)`, but inserts them into a list instead, since lists are ordered.

It also flattens the list with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which is `O(n)`.

Then you can simply run this function on as many lists as you want:

```
>>> list_a = ['abc','bcd','dcb']
>>> list_b = ['abc','xyz','ASD']
>>> list_c = ['AZD','bxd','qwe']
>>> print(union_lists(list_a, list_b, list_c))
['abc', 'bcd', 'dcb', 'xyz', 'ASD', 'AZD', 'bxd', 'qwe']
>>> list_d = ['bcd', 'AGF', 'def']
>>> print(union_lists(list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d))
['abc', 'bcd', 'dcb', 'xyz', 'ASD', 'AZD', 'bxd', 'qwe', 'AGF', 'def']
```